# Libpng error in a iOS 5.0 compilation using XCODE 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

When I try to load a Triangle, I'm getting the next error:

`Mesh_Mesh_Box001.001: 35: GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP
libpng error: CgBI: unknown critical chunk`

But this works on a different example.

What is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try changing PNG compresion flag.

Go to your projects Build Settings and look for "Compress PNG Files". Then change the flag to "No" value.

After this, first clean the project before rebuild. It must work!

;)